# Wine Visual C++ redistributable for Visual Studio 2015

Tags: wine

When I want to run Chessbase 14 I get this error output:

```
gratis@Aurora:~$ env WINEPREFIX="/home/gratis/.wine" wine C:\\Program\ Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\CBase14.exe 
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library VCRUNTIME140.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-multibyte-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library mfc140.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\BCGCBPro140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library VCRUNTIME140.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\BCGCBPro140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\BCGCBPro140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\BCGCBPro140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-multibyte-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\BCGCBPro140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\BCGCBPro140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\BCGCBPro140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\BCGCBPro140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\BCGCBPro140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\BCGCBPro140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\BCGCBPro140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\BCGCBPro140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\BCGCBPro140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library BCGCBPro140.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\CBase14.exe") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library VCRUNTIME140.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-multibyte-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library mfc140.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\BCGCBPro140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library VCRUNTIME140.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\BCGCBPro140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\BCGCBPro140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\BCGCBPro140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-multibyte-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\BCGCBPro140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\BCGCBPro140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\BCGCBPro140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\BCGCBPro140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\BCGCBPro140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\BCGCBPro140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\BCGCBPro140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\BCGCBPro140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\BCGCBPro140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library BCGCBPro140.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\SView4.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library VCRUNTIME140.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-multibyte-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library mfc140.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\SView4.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library VCRUNTIME140.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\MSVCP140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\MSVCP140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\MSVCP140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\MSVCP140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\MSVCP140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\MSVCP140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\MSVCP140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-multibyte-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\MSVCP140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\MSVCP140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\MSVCP140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\MSVCP140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\MSVCP140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\MSVCP140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library MSVCP140.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\SView4.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library VCRUNTIME140.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\SView4.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\SView4.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\SView4.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\SView4.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\SView4.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\SView4.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\SView4.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-multibyte-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\SView4.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\SView4.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\SView4.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\SView4.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library SView4.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\CBase14.exe") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library VCRUNTIME140.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\MSVCP140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\MSVCP140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\MSVCP140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\MSVCP140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\MSVCP140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\MSVCP140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\MSVCP140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-multibyte-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\MSVCP140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\MSVCP140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\MSVCP140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\MSVCP140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\MSVCP140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\MSVCP140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library MSVCP140.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\CBase14.exe") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library VCRUNTIME140.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-multibyte-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mfc140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library mfc140.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\CBase14.exe") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library VCRUNTIME140.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\CBase14.exe") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\CBase14.exe") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\CBase14.exe") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\CBase14.exe") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\CBase14.exe") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\CBase14.exe") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\CBase14.exe") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\CBase14.exe") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\CBase14.exe") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\CBase14.exe") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-multibyte-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\CBase14.exe") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\CBase14.exe") not found
err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Main exe initialization for L"C:\\Program Files\\ChessBase\\CBase14\\CBase14.exe" failed, status c0000135
gratis@Aurora:~$
```

So I figured I should install "Visual C++ redistributable for Visual Studio 2015" after some internet research. But just downloading it and "running with a wine program loader" does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First install winetricks: `sudo apt install winetricks`.

Then run `winetricks vcrun2015` .

To have the latest one run: `wget  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks`

Then run: `bash winetricks vcrun2015`

Then try installing and running your application. I see that there is no entry in **Wine AppDB** or in http://www.codeweavers.com so probably this application is too new to run on it. Until version 12 is reported it is working.

Regards

Comment: <pre>

gratis@Aurora:~$ winetricks vcrun2015
Unknown arg vcrun2015

<pre>

Comment: probably your winetricks is too old. I will update the answer for the command to download the latest

Comment: it actually says: vcrun2015 already installed, skipping
So I guess the problem is due to something else?

Comment: You are welcome!. I recommend you starting from scratch, because the VC 2015 was installed by hand. Just `run rm -rf ~/.wine` and start again

Comment: I got `Note: command wine vc_redist.x86.exe returned status 180.  Aborting.`, more on https://pastebin.com/6NsDyZWk Maybe this indicates the problem? `You are using a 64-bit WINEPREFIX. Note that many verbs only install 32-bit versions of packages.`

Comment: "You are using a 64-bit WINEPREFIX" this is your problem. Your installer is 32 bit. Just delete  ~/.wine and then run `env WINEARCH=win32 winecfg` it will configure your wine in 32 bit

Comment: vcrun2015, vcrun2017 (and 2019) Discussion · Issue #1190 · Winetricks/winetricks
https://github.com/Winetricks/winetricks/issues/1190

Comment: Upvoted, this is the best answer and necessary to make python 3.5 and up work. http://realtechtalk.com/How_To_Install_python_34_35_and_up_on_Linux_with_wine_Working_Solution-2288-articles