# Dev C++ Output Screen not coming

Tags: compiling, c++, runit

I installed Dev C++ using Wine on Ubuntu 18.04 and the program is compiling but it not showing any output screen.

Comment: Hi, if you do not have a really specific purpose to use Dev C++ which is native for windows you can take a look on various different IDE don't need an additional layer to work on linux. An example here: https://www.tecmint.com/best-linux-ide-editors-source-code-editors/

Answer (score 1):

Code::Blocks from the default Ubuntu repositories is an alternative to **Dev-C++** with similar features. Code::Blocks is a cross-platform Integrated Development Environment (IDE). It is based on a self-developed plugin framework allowing unlimited extensibility. Most of its functionality is already provided by plugins. Plugins included in the base package are:

- Compiler frontend to many free compilers
- Debugger frontend for GDB
- Source formatter (based on AStyle)
- Wizard to create new C++ classes
- Code-completion / symbols-browser (work in progress)
- Default MIME handler
- Wizard to create new Code::Blocks plugins
- To-do list
- Extensible wizard based on scripts
- Autosave (saves your work in the unfortunate case of a crash)

Compare this functionality to the functionality of Dev-C++ and you'll see the resemblance, so it's worth a try.

To install Code::Blocks open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install codeblocks g++ xterm gdb # optional g++-8
```

Comment: Thank you . Code Blocks  worked for me . But I would still like to know the reason for output screen not showing in Dev C++

Comment: I see!  How do I do that?

Comment: Go to `/home/username/.wine/dosdevices/c:/Dev-Cpp` (For me the directory for Wine is in my own user's home directory. You just need to run it separately through browse to c: drive, then where you saved your project and run it using Wine.

Comment: Maybe you don't need to install this program because you have C++ installed already, but if you do need it here is the link for instructions on how to install it in Ubuntu: [Wine Visual C++ redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://askubuntu.com/questions/852407/wine-visual-c-redistributable-for-visual-studio-2015) link to download it: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu's official repository still has Code::Blocks 16.01 but the latest is 17.12. The command provided by Karel in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1076385/816190) will install Code::Blocks v16.01. To install Code::Blocks v17.12, download it from [here](http://codeblocks.org/downloads/26). Then run:

```
tar -xf codeblocks_17.12-1_amd64_stable.tar.xz
sudo dpkg -i *17.12*.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Reference: [N0rbert's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1030734/816190)